# The number of six-lettered words such that neither the pattern "ace" nor "fd" appears

Tags: probability

The number of six-lettered words that can be formed using the letters $a,b,c,d,e$ and $f$ without repetition such that neither the pattern "ace" nor "fd" appears is 
$(A)582\hspace{1cm}(B)482\hspace{1cm}(C)660\hspace{1cm}(D)$None of these

---

Total words without any restrictions are $6!$
But how will we find number of words with this given condition,i am stuck.Please help me.

Comment: Have you heard about the inclusion-exclusion principle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's call the set of all words $W$, the subsets of those containing $\sf ace$ $A$ and the set of words containing $\sf fd$ $F$. We are interested in $|W \setminus (A \cup F)|$, now 
$$ |A \cup F| = |A| + |F| - |A \cap F| $$
Let's look at $|A|$. We have to make words out of the four "letters" - now $\sf ace$ counts as one letter! -  $\sf (ace)$, $\sf b, d, f$. There are $4!$ of them, so $|A| = 4!$.

For $|F|$, we have the letters $\sf a, b, c, e, fd$, hence $|F| = 5!$.

For $|A \cap F|$, we have the letters $\sf ace, b, fd$, hence $|A \cap F| = 3!$. This gives 
$$ |W \setminus A \cup F| = 6! - (4! + 5! - 3!) = 3! \cdot (120 - 4 - 20 + 1) = 6 \cdot 97 = 582 $$

Answer (score 1):

You should treat "ace" as a token and then you are permuting this token with b,f,d, totally $4!$ and we have $6!-4!$ left. Then you treat fd as a token and we have $6!-4!-5!$ left. But you have minused those have both "ace" and "fd" twice so we need to add once back, giving us the final answer $6!-4!-5!+3!=582$